# Does this piece of text, below, follow a correct grammar?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, vocabulary

This piece of text was found today in the streets of Amsterdam. I was wondering if its grammar is correct.

> Wandered walker sewn onto the shadowy night.
> Vindictively I swear to be casted you,
> into the leaves of descendants you came.

Comment: Do they still have those marijuana coffee shops?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey AFAIK, it's residents only now...

Comment: Yep, they do. I don't know if only residents. Alas, the red district is now closed due specific regulations. @MichaelHarvey

Comment: So the text might not be stoned drivel?

Comment: To acquire that knowledge I must ask the author who I regard as anonym  @MichaelHarvey

Comment: Bad English could be good poetry. Key word, could.

Comment: Perhaps a future Rimbaud...

Comment: My question is, is he/she/it using correct grammar? @YosefBaskin

Comment: It is not valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Yet as a tourist I don't know why @HotLicks

Comment: @SNR...are you a native-speaker? And /or a Dutch citizen?

Comment: @Cascabel No, none of them. For that reason I came here to ask you.

Comment: Well, this is going to be problematic. As a non-native speaker, you say "some graffiti was found" in the streets...in this day and age of wi-fi and the ubiquitous cell phone, and still we have no proof that this is real.

Comment: @Cascabel And yet, I just can't see the reason why shouldn't be answered.

Comment: It's off-topic: it's proof-reading, Primarily-Opinion-Based, litcrit, etc.

Comment: (scratching my head) Is asking for grammar and syntactical analysis off topic?

Comment: Your words are orders to me, Cesar. @Cascabel

Comment: @SNR ELU is not a random sentence explainer service. Even [ell.se], which deals helping people with difficulties of grammaticality, probably doesn't deal with this kind of question.

Comment: @Mitch Perhaps some people think this is a platform to expose their prose...As Sven said [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12000/where-is-the-limit-for-posting-filth-in-the-name-of-creativity)

Comment: If you insist on bluntness, the English is not correct and the poetry is not my taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wandered walker sewn onto the shadowy night.

No. An article (a) should be used, so:

> A wandered walker, sewn onto the shadowy night.

> Vindictively I swear to be casted you, into the leaves of descendants you came.

Also no.

- *Vindictively* is a fronted adverbial. (You would cast him into something vindictively, for example.)
- *[T]o be casted*, in conjunction with *you*, is incorrect; it should say *to cast you*.
- There should not be a comma after the first *you*.
- *[T]he leaves of descendants you came* should say *the leaves of your descendants.

So:

> Vindictively, I swear to cast you into the leaves of your descendants.